# how to search for table with field datatype datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have model with the name job i want to search datetime field.

my method is here  :

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
        where('reference_no ILIKE? OR status ILIKE? OR summary ILIKE? OR due_date LIKE?', "%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%" )
    else
       scoped
    end
  end
```

please tell me how to search due_date column its data type is datetime

Comment: I don't know what is you asking for. But you can get your model's column type like this: `Job.columns_hash["name"].type`. Are you looking for this?

Answer (score 1):

If i am getting your question perfectly then you are searching for the field having datatype "datetime"

For that you have make it like this

```
Job.columns_hash["field_name"].type.to_s
```

It will return with field type "datetime" in string format